# Why does $J_{\lambda ,l} -\lambda I_l$ map the standard basis vectors $e_i$ of $\mathbb{C}^l$ to $e_{i-1}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

I'm going through the general method of how you construct the Jordan-normal form of a matrix $A$ and my notes say that 
$$J_{\lambda ,l} -\lambda I_l : e_l \mapsto e_{l-1} \ldots e_2 \mapsto e_1 \mapsto 0$$
where $J_{\lambda ,l}$ is the elementary Jordan block of the eigenvalue $\lambda$, $I_l$ is the identity matrix of size $l\times l$ and $e_1 ,\ldots ,e_l$ are the vectors of the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^l$.

Why do these basis vectors map this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As

$$J_{\lambda,l} = \begin{bmatrix}
\lambda & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & \lambda & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \lambda & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & \lambda & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & \lambda
\end{bmatrix},$$

we see that

$$J_{\lambda,l} - \lambda I_l = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Note that

$$(J_{\lambda,l} - \lambda I_l)x = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\vdots\\
x_{l-3}\\
x_{l-2}\\
x_{l-1}\\
x_l
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4\\
\vdots\\
x_{l-2}\\
x_{l-1}\\
x_l\\
0
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Therefore, for $2 \leq i \leq l$, $(J_{\lambda, l} - \lambda I_l)e_l = e_{l-1}$ and $(J_{\lambda, l} - \lambda I_l)e_1 = 0$.